# Issue with LVM partition after adding space on physical partition

Tags: partition, lvm

The OS is based on a CentOS 5.5.
After adding space on physical partition, the OS went in emergency mode.
I tried to fix that and ended with no boot at all, with stuck at GRUB screen with error 17

[image]

It's seem that /dev/sda1 is wrong (that space was added to that disk)
I cannot grow the partition with gparted

[image]

So I booted with a LiveUSB CentOS 6, but same thing, I cannot make alive that partition.
(A bit strange bit /dev/sda in gparted ended with /dev/sdb in LiveUSB)

[image]

[image]

We do have a VGdata, but it's not shown here.

Do you have any idea to make this partition come back alive ?
lvm partitions are still a mystery for me

Thanks in advance !